# Finding a calculated ratios less than the average (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT 
    PlayerName, ROUND(SUM(A)/SUM(TO),2) AS ATORatio
FROM 
    Players_t 
INNER JOIN 
    GameStats_t ON Players_t.JerseyNumber=GameStats_t.JerseyNumber
WHERE 
    ATORatio < (SELECT SUM(A)/SUM(TO) FROM GameStats_t)
GROUP BY 
    PlayerName;
```

I need to return all players who have an `ATORatio` less than the average. Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: When I do that, MS Access asks me to enter a parameter value for ATORatio (I literally copy and pasted the WHERE line below the group by and changed it to HAVING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should help:

```
SELECT 
    PlayerName, ROUND(SUM(A)/SUM(TO),2) AS ATORatio
FROM 
    Players_t 
INNER JOIN 
    GameStats_t ON Players_t.JerseyNumber=GameStats_t.JerseyNumber
GROUP BY 
    PlayerName;
HAVING             ----> You can also use WHERE here
    ROUND(SUM(A)/SUM(TO),2) < (SELECT SUM(A)/SUM(TO) FROM GameStats_t)
```

The issue is, ATORatio would not be known initially, while executing the where  or having clause. Hence you need to use the field ATORatio's value itself in the where or having clause.

Comment: @WilliamSmolen: If it helped you, please accept as answer and upvote when you have sufficient reputation! :)